Do I need preg_replace_callback() to replace all matches in a text?
As part of a migration, I wrote a function to transform links, prepending a path ("/my/files") to existing paths from the source site.  Here is my function:
function example_file_urls($text) {

  $extensions = "(\.docx|\.doc|\.pdf|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.jpeg)";

  // Transform URLs from https://www.example.com with a matching extension.
  $pattern[0] = '/<a (.*)href="https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/(.*)' . $extensions . '"(.*)>(.*)<\/a>/i';

  // Transform relative URLs other than fragments and the result of the first pattern.
  $pattern[1] = '/<a (.*)href="(?!http|#|\/my\/files)(.*)' . $extensions . '"(.*)>(.*)<\/a>/i';

  // Fix double forward slash.
  $pattern[2] = '/<a (.*)href="\/my\/files\/\/(.*)' . $extensions . '"(.*)>(.*)<\/a>/i';

  $r = '<a $1href="/my/files/$2$3"$4>$5</a>';
  $replacement[0] = $r;
  $replacement[1] = $r;
  $replacement[2] = $r;

  $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);

  return $text;

}

It works well, but only transforms the last matching link in the text.  I want to transform all links.  In my research on this, it seems preg_replace_callback() might be necessary, but I always thought preg_replace was intended to make multiple replacements in a file, and that is why there is an optional $limit parameter.  So it might be a wrong turn to use preg_replace_callback().  Is there some simpler adjustment I can make to the function so it replaces all matching strings in the text, or do I need preg_replace_callback()?  I figure I would just be calling preg_replace() in the callback, so intuitively it doesn't make sense that I would to wrap everything in preg_replace_callback().

If you are performing string-function surgery on a valid HTML document, then you are having an XY Problem.  Your question does not contain a [mcve]. Where is the sample input and your desired output?

I doubt it works "well". To answer your question: .* is greedy (all you can eat). preg_replace_callback() can't help here, regex is the wrong tool for this.

@bobblebubble this question Needs Debugging Details.

@arnold make your life easier and parse the document properly, then if regex is needed, the challenge is much smaller and therefore far less likely to break. PHP DomDocument editing all links

@mickmackusa Certainly "...only transforms the last matching link..." suggests greed vs lazy (demo) which is good to know anyways.

I don't disagree with your guess @bobble I was hoping that you would do the expected action of voting to close a page that is not currently suitable for this site.

Relevant reading: PHP change href when condition is met and Replace the href value of qualifying 's using the tag's visible text and Change the href attribute of  tags in an html document and Use PHP DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile to modify all hrefs and make them absolute
